# how to detect libConfigurer64.dylib is loaded at runtime in mac app objective c

Tags: objective-c, dylib

I am trying to find if someone tries to `libConfigurer64.dylib` runtime
so i have imported this in
`#import <mach-o/dyld.h>` Appdelegate then in `didFinishLaunching`

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
int imageCount = _dyld_image_count();
for (int i=0; i < imageCount; i++) {
   NSLog(@"%d - %s", i, _dyld_get_image_name(i));
}
```

I was able to see other dylb libraries(like libobjc.A.dylib , libSystem.B.dylib , libc++abi.dylib etc.) in log but couldn't find `libConfigurer64.dylib`
any specific reason.

Any Suggestion?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Does your binary show load command libConfigurer64.dylib? run "otool -l" on your app.

Comment: on running this command on terminal getting this `at least one file must be specified`

Comment: Read what it says. google is your friend